# Android AnimationListener does not get hit

Tags: android, animation, listener

I want to create some sort of imageGallery with two different animations.
When clicking on the currently visibly image, an "OK-Image" shall fade in (1 Second, not repeated), after the animation is finished, the next image should be shown

Each Image has an infinite repeated animation (normal view, zoomed view)

so ..

- Step 1: Infinite Animation of an image (normal => zoom => normal..)
- Step 2: Click
- Step 3: Show "OK-Image" (fade in 1 sec)
- Step 1 ...

The problem is, that the Animation Listener of the OK-Animation gets hit, the Animationlistener of the infinite animation does not..

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   fadeInOKAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeinonce);
   fadePermanentAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeininfinite);
   fadeInOKAnimation.setAnimationListener(fadeInOKAnimationListener);        
   fadePermanentAnimation.setAnimationListener(fadePermanentAnimationListener);
}


AnimationListener fadeInOKAnimationListener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {

   public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
   { 
      ThreadHelper.sleep(500);
      imgMessung.clearAnimation();
      int currentImageId = currentStateImage.getNormalImage();
      imgMessung.clearAnimation();
      imgMessung.setImageResource(currentImageId);
      imgMessung.startAnimation(fadePermanentAnimation);
   }

   public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

   public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }
};


AnimationListener fadePermanentAnimationListener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {

   public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) { }

   public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

      StateImage currentStateImage = messung.GetCurrentImage();

      if(currentImageState == ImageState.Normal)
      {
         int currentImageId = Integer.parseInt(currentStateImage.getNormalImage());
         imgMessung.setImageResource(currentImageId);
      }
      else
      {
         int currentImageId = Integer.parseInt(currentStateImage.getZoomedImage());
         imgMessung.setImageResource(currentImageId);
      }
   }

   public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no end for endless animation, so nothing will be triggered. You may want to use [onAnimationRepeat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html#onAnimationRepeat%28android.view.animation.Animation%29) to know where animation is restarted (but then - what you need endless repetition for? If you need some elements to animate endlessly (i.e. spinning busy marker), wrap it on i.e. `FrameLayout` and plant your animation and listener there

Comment: i am already using onAnimationRepeat for the fadePermanentAnimationListener animation .. but this does not get hit